# Amending 2015 Tax Return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1040x, amended-tax-return, form-1040

When I filed my original Form 1040, I owed the IRS $274. After the return was accepted, I realized I could be claimed as a dependent and now need to amend.

The amended Form 1040 shows that I owe the IRS $551 on line 78. However, that does not take into account the $274 I already paid with my original return. Form 1040X already accounts for it on line 16, so according to Form 1040X I only owe $277 on line 20.

Where in Form 1040 can I put the $274 I already paid with my original return so that its line 78 matches with line 20 of From 1040X at $277?

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere. Form 1040 shouldn't match the form 1040X. The form 1040X highlights the differences between the 1040 originally filed and the correct 1040.